# Payment without having paypal account from a site where the payment gateway is the paypal

Tags: php, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

I want to integrate paypal in my site. Visitors will buy products from my site. But my customers may not have paypal a/c.

I want my customers to buy products from my site .

1. through master card,credit card etc.. who doesn't have paypal account
2. through paypal a/c who does have paypal a/c

I created paypal "Pay Now" button and used my seller merchant a/c as the value of "business" hidden field. But it redirects to the page where it asks to login into paypal a/c, which means that my customer must have a paypal a/c. But what about those customers who doesn't have paypal a/c?

Please help.

Comment: wen u go with paypal customer need paypal account surly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it redirects to the PayPal page. But there is a section which you can pay using your debit or credit card.

Please go to below link and there you can see that.

[Paypal login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrrP5.png)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Before getting that section we get "Please login to use the PayPal Sandbox features."That means we need to first login and then we'll get the option either through creditcard etc or paypal a/c.But I am asking what when the vistior has not registered him self in paypal and wanto pay through credtit card in site where paypal is integrated as a payment gateway.

Comment: No you don't need to have a PayPal account. Did you use "PayPal Express Checkout" method? You can check this on www.webr.ly go this site. then create a new account. Login. In  the footer click your username. then click Upgrade. Then click purchase. You will see the page as mentioned earlier

Comment: Thanks a lot Manahara for the answer through example.Now I have been cleared that through PaypalPro one can make his visitors to pay without having paypal a/c in a website where the payment gateway is paypal.I integrated paypal express checkout code and used the sandbox credential to test.But again itz giving 2 options.1>"Pay through Paypal account" which is fine.but another option is to signup 2>"create a paypal account",in place of which i need the option "Pay with credit or debit card".Is it bcz of sandbox credentials?Will i get "Pay with credit/debit card" by using real paypal credentials?

Comment: No sandbox works the same way as real paypal works. May be you are passing extra fields When you call "SetExpressCheckout" API.
Pass these fields:
1) USER,
2) PWD,
3) SIGNATURE,
4) VERSION,
5) PAYMENTACTION,
6) AMT,
7) RETURNURL,
8) CANCELURL,
9) METHOD

You can find more API references from this link,
https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/setexpresscheckout-api-operation-nvp
Good Luck !

Answer (score 2):

Customers without paypal account can easily do a payment that too without going to paypal. YOu have use DoDirectPayment NVP of API.
Check out this link. It is the method which will help you make a payment using dodirectpayment method. Though you will need a seller account on paypal which will receive funds.
https://www.x.com/paypal-apis-dodirectpayment-php-5.3/nvp

### Understanding the Method

https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/dodirectpayment-api-operation-nvp

### Explaination with code

http://vikku.info/programming/payment-gateway/paypal-pro-direct-payment-NVP-sale-explained.htm

so basically, Just search for DoDirectPayment Method and its related help and you will get the answer as this method does everything.